# Why pointer is giving the same address for all array blocks?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

Here is a program, I write it to output all the characters of a string one by one. But I also print the address of individual blocks of the array. The problem is addresses for all blocks are same. Why?
Does someone know?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char enter[]="Kinsman";
    char *ptr;  
    ptr=enter;
    int i=0;
    while(*ptr!='\0')
    {
        printf("%c%p\n",*ptr,&ptr);
        ptr++;
        for(i=0;i<=100000000;i++);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(i=0;i<=100000000;i++);` ?? why this

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Back on my old ATARI 800XL, waiting one second was accomplished easily with `FOR I=1 TO 500: NEXT I`. But this method - waiting in terms of cycles - has been outdated for about 20 years.

Comment: @glglgl Yes I read it somewhere in past and it will consume CPU cycles. ~~ But a C compiler can optimize it by replacing `i = 100000000;`.. it is not reliable. Correct?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I used it just to give a pause for each output through loop.

Comment: @glglgl From your comments it looks like you both are professionals.

Comment: @AshishTomer It is better to use the appropriate function - `sleep()` or `usleep()` on Unix, `Sleep()` on WIndows.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan This is right. Most modern compilers will probably optimize it away; forgot about that.

Comment: @glglgl: Or if you can use C11, [thrd_sleep](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/thrd_sleep) would be a cross-platform solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing the address of the pointer, not the value of the pointer

Try

```
printf("%c%p\n",*ptr, static_cast<void*>(ptr));
```

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/18929285/259)

Comment: I printed the value and address both using %c and %p

Comment: @AshishTomer Yes but you also added `&`, read answer again. `&ptr` should be just `ptr` in printf

Comment: @AshishTomer: You might want to see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/930138/183120) for `clrscr`.

Comment: Using `%p` without a `void *` is *undefined behavior*. Unless the argument is a ptr-to-void, a cast is required.

Comment: @DavidSykes what are standards? And where can I get them?

Comment: @AshishTomer If you are referring to the standard c++ library then it should come with your compiler. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/

Comment: @DavidSykes Okay. . . I am using GCC. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Because you print the address of the actual pointer.

When you use `&ptr` you get the address of the actual pointer and not the address if points to. Remove the ampersand (address-of operator `&`) so you have only `ptr`.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thank you! :)
Can you tell me how do I clear screen on startup using clrscr()?

Comment: @AshishTomer By calling the function?

Comment: No i know that actually I added conio.h but GCC gives error:
"reverse.c:2:18: fatal error: conio.h: No such file or directory
 #include<conio.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated."

Comment: @AshishTomer What is the point of clearing the "screen"? As a user, this would annoy me as I lose track of what happened before. Is this really absolutely necessary?

Comment: @glglgl no! It's not necessary. I just wanted to :P :D

Comment: @AshishTomer The `<conio.h>` header file and its associated functions are a Windows and specifically VisualStudio (VisualC++) thing (originally from old TurboC if I remember correctly). GCC does not have it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg okay. thnx

Answer (score 1):

`ptr` is a pointer and it is also a variable in stack that has an address. This is fixed, while what it points to is varying by `ptr++`, thus you've to print the pointed-to value and not the address of the pointer itself.

```
 printf("%c%p\n",*ptr, (void*)ptr);
 //                   ^  remove & , and add void*
```

Comment: Can you tell me how do I clear screen?
<br/>I added conio.h but GCC gives error: "reverse.c:2:18: fatal error: conio.h: **No such file or directory** #include<conio.h> ^ compilation terminated."