# Comparing strings in qsort

Tags: c++, string, qsort

Whenever I am comparing string in qsort, the order is completely wrong. For example, the input is

```
45 4 9 22 2
```

but my output is

```
22 45 4 9 2
```

here is my comparing function

```
int cmpString(const void *a, const void *b) {
  const Node *a1 = *(const Node **)a;
  const Node *b1 = *(const Node **)b;

  return a1->s.c_str() - b1->s.c_str();
}
```

and dont tell me to use sort(), I can't for this assignment

Comment: Shortcut: [std::string::compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare).

Comment: *and dont tell me to use sort()* -- The standard tells you this is undefined behavior.  [See this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort), and pay attention to this passage:  *The type of the elements of the array must be a TrivialType, otherwise the behavior is undefined.* -- Tell your teacher to have a look and ponder what they're teaching you.  If you're calling `qsort` on an array of `std::string`, then your code is broken, regardless if you accepted the answers given.

Comment: An array of non-trivial types is also no good.  So if `Node` is a non-trivial type, then `qsort` can't be used, regardless of the restrictions made to you by the teacher.  No C++ program should be using `qsort`, unless there is something inherently "better" in using `qsort` (with the caveat that it only works for non-trivial types).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is your code's major problem.

```
return a1->s.c_str() - b1->s.c_str();
```

The reason behind this is that you are subtracting two pointers here which is not what comparator is supposed to do in this case. Comparator does the comparison on the basis of content.

Instead, try this:

```
int length1 = a1->s.size();
int length2 = b1->s.size();

for (int i = 0; i < min(length1, length2); i++) {
    if (a1->s[i] != b1->s[i]) { // if characters are not same, return difference of their ASCII values.
        return a1->s[i] - b1->s[i];
    }
}

return length1 - length2; // if they are same till now, then shorter string should appear first. That's why it is required.
```

**Suggestion:**

If you are coding in C++, then please use STL. There is a nice function `sort()` given by `<algorithm>` which allows you to do the same thing without using `void *`

**Update:**

As rightly suggested by [user4581301](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4581301/user4581301), you may use std::string::compare directly.

Like this:

```
return (a1->s).compare(b1->s);
```

Comment: That was it! Really appreciate it.

Comment: @jordanneely If you think this really answered your question, please consider voting and accepting. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: If you're using `qsort` on an array of `std::string` or on a struct/class that contains a `std::string` member, forget it.  The behavior is undefined.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Are you sure? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18929285/5859925